# Difficulty in understanding the definition of entire function of complex variable.

Tags: complex-analysis

The definition of entire function goes as: An entire function is a function that is analytic at each point in the entire finite plane.

Now I have a complex function $f(z)= \frac{1}{z}$. 
I know that this function is analytic at each non zero point in the finite plane. So is it an entire function?

This question arose for me as it is not defined at value $0$, but in the definition for a function to be finite, it has to be analytic at each point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the definition says your function has to be analytic at each point in the plane. $1/z$ is not analytic at each point in the plane, as you already observe, so it's not entire.

Answer (score 0):

$f(z)=1/z$ is not entire.  It must be analytic at every point of $\mathbb C$.  In order for that to be true, the function must be defined at every point of $\mathbb C$.